# Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment not working (for me)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I used Word macro recorder to left justify this paragraph:

```
        Bha fear dhiubh, air an  .....
```

The macro worked using this:

Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft

My vba code attempts to do the same thing with this:

```
For Each parEach In docSource.Paragraphs
    parEach.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
Next
```

Compiles and runs OK but does nothing!

I tried vba Replace function with vbTab - nothing!

I also managed to do it manually using Find&Replace by copying the long 'white space' at the start of the paragraph.  That worked too.

So I can do it manually but not using code.

Comment: As you are adjusting the formatting of each paragraph it may be it may be simpler to set the formatting via the Style.  e.g. docSource.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft.  However, this will not succeed if there is any local paragraph formatting which overides the style based formatting.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
docSource.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
```